# Creating a UNIX account which only executes one command

Tags: ssh, login, solaris, account-restrictions

Is there a way to create a user account in Solaris which allows the users to run one command only? No login shell or anything else. I could possibly do it with `/usr/bin/false` in `/etc/passwd` and just get the user to `ssh <hostname> <command>`, but is there a nicer way to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could used a [forced command](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html) if the users can only connect through ssh. Essentially, whenever the user connects through ssh with a certain key and a certain username, you force him to execute a command (or a script or) you determined in the .ssh/authorized_keys. Commands issued by the users will be ignored.

For example:

```
# in .ssh/authorized_keys
command="cd /foo/bar && /path/to/scripts/my_script.sh arg1 arg2",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa public_key
```

Comment: Well you were both right. What I done was created a script which supplies a menu on the prompt and used the forced check command in .ssh/authorized_keys on the server in front of the key for the authorized user. This now enables him to ssh to the server and at the prompt is given a nice menu with several commands to execute. Nothing else can be run. Happy days!

Comment: Edited; you need these options to secure a forced command: "no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty".

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: If you're using openssh server 7.2 or later (which you probably are by now), you can use the single option "restrict" instead of all the "no-" options.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560127/135943

Answer (score 12):

You could set the shell of that user to a script just running the command you want to allow: Whenever the user logs in, the command is run, then the user is logged out. And since there's no "full shell" you don't have to deal with the user trying funky stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you could do this with RBAC and giving the user a privileged shell (pfsh, pfcsh, or pfksh) and creating a profile for the commands the user(s) would be allowed to run.