# Open screen in terminal after user login

Tags: debian, terminal, gnu-screen, login, performance

When a user logins to my Debian server using e.g. Putty, I need to perform the following:

1. It will automatically execute command `screen -r MyWindow`, and
2. the user won't be able to leave the screen window, so I want the user to have disabled all commands.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do these users login locally, too? And if so, shall screen not be started in this case?

Comment: You need give a much better description of your problem! 1. you can tie users only to sessions, not windows. 2. Without recompiling screen, you cannot prevent a user from issuing commands.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a screenrc that disables interactive commands (it may not be tamper-proof).

```
unbindall
escape ""
defescape ""
shell /bin/false
```

Use it to start your screen server. Then attach to the same screen server on login, using an [SSH forced command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3556/creating-a-unix-account-which-only-executes-one-command).