# ssh: force different shell for non-interactive command execution

Tags: shell, ssh, zsh, environment-variables, dash

how can I force specific shell to be used for non-interactive command execution via `ssh` on remote server?

My default shell on the remote server is `zsh`, but I need to execute given command using `/bin/sh`. When I run following command, `foo` will be executed by `zsh` (as expected):

```
ssh -tq -l root -o LogLevel=ERROR remote-server "foo"
```

I have tried specifying `/bin/sh -c "foo"`, but that only causes `zsh` to launch `/bin/sh` which then executes `foo`.

I need to use `/bin/sh` directly, not via `zsh`

Is there some option to `ssh`, or some settings either local or remote, so that I can define different shell?

Can I set different shell for all non-interactive commands (non login shell) ?

Comment: I don't think you can. It would allow bypassing any restrictions set by the user having a restricted shell, or `/bin/false` as their shell. Even the `ForceCommand` directive in `sshd_config` says "The command is invoked by using the user's login
 shell with the -c option." But does it matter if zsh is executed in between? It'll read zsh's startup files, instead of those of `/bin/sh` (if any) but there shouldn't be anything stopping you from loading those manually, or setting whatever you want from somewhere else.

Comment: Create a new user, specify `/bin/sh` as the login shell and use that user to perform your remote commands.

Comment: A user should not be able to bypass its login shell in ssh, by design. If you're able to do that, it's either because you misconfigured your server or because you found a bug. @ilkkachu: zsh does not source any startup files when run **non-interactively** via ssh. Only bash does that.

Comment: @ktzap, 5.1 Startup/Shutdown Files: "Commands are first read from /etc/zshenv; this cannot be overridden. [...]" -- https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Files In any case, I was mostly wondering why the in-between zsh could be a problem, and startup files with something really odd was the only thing I could come up with. (Which doesn't mean there couldn't be some other issue, of course.)

Comment: Depending on why you need "foo" run by sh, it may work to use `emulate sh; foo` as the command with zsh. That means any evaluation of foo will be sh-compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to bypass the login shell, by design. You can set an SSH account whose shell is restricted (e.g. a restricted shell as in rsh/rksh/rbash/…, or a shell that only allows some specific protocol such as rssh or git-shell). The client cannot specify a different shell.

To run code in a different shell, you have to make your login shell run that shell and pass the code to the inner shell. This is no different from what you'd need to do to run interpreted code in some other language such as perl, python, etc. Take care of quoting correctly. If you don't need standard input, pass the script on standard input, so that you don't need nested quoting.

It is possible to have multiple entries in the user database for the same account. “Same account” means the same user ID. The entries must have different user names and can have different passwords, different shells, etc. See [Can you give a user account multiple passwords?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90684/can-you-give-a-user-account-multiple-passwords/90947#90947). Beware that this is not very robust because some programs do a lookup from the user ID (rather than from the user name in the `$USER` environment variable which is set to the name the user chose when logging in).

If you want zsh for interactive use but a Bourne-style shell for SSH, you can do what I do: I set my login shell to `/bin/sh` (or whatever it takes to have a POSIX shell), and I have (some more complicated version of) `export SHELL=/bin/zsh; exec $SHELL` in my `.profile`.

Comment: See also [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/205567) for how to run a given command (like `sh`, with `-c` and `some arbitrary code` arguments) over ssh regardless of the login shell of the user there.