# Relationship between options in authorized_keys and options in sshd_config?

Tags: openssh, sshd

I'd like to configure an SSH Daemon on one of my servers so that certain users on remote clients can execute certain commands on the server. Each user, identified by a certain public key, must be able to execute a command specific to him.

In general, there seem to be many options to do this, three of them being:

- `ForceCommand ...` in `sshd_config`: This is not flexible enough in my case since each of those users (public keys) should trigger another command.
- `command="..."` in `authorized_keys`: This is ideally suited for my situation since each user has an individual `authorized_keys` file in his home directory on that server and thus each user can execute his own, individual command. But I have an understanding problem with that method which leads me to the question detailed below.
- The `/usr/lib/restricted-ssh-commands` method: This method is a little bit oversized for my use case because each of my users needs only one command to execute; furthermore, the regular expressions which are used with this method must be crafted very carefully, because they impose a security risk otherwise.

As noted above, I would like to opt for second method. However, in every tutorial I have read (and that was a lot, e.g. [this one](https://research.kudelskisecurity.com/2013/05/14/restrict-ssh-logins-to-a-single-command/)) it was stressed that we should add not only the `command=...` option in the `authorized_keys` files, but several more, like so:

```
command="/bin/foo bar baz",no-port-forwarding,no-x11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding ssh-rsa ...
```

Now I am worried about the relationship between `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (where I already have configured all daemon options which are important to me system-wide) and the options in the `authorized_keys` files.

I have read `man authorized_keys` which gave me the impression that `authorized_keys` takes precedence over `sshd_config` for the options which are in both of them. However, it isn't clearly stated (unless I have missed it) what happens with the options which are not in `authorized_keys`, but are in `sshd_config`; will they be taken from `sshd_config`?

To give a real example: `no-x11-forwarding` is one of the options we can (and should, according to all tutorials I have read) use in `authorized_keys`. But I already have `X11Forwarding no` in `sshd_config`. So what happens if I leave `no-x11-forwarding` away from `authorized_keys`?

Having to include all relevant options in each `authorized_keys` file would be a little dumb IMHO, but once again, every tutorial I have come across stressed that we should do it.

I would be grateful if somebody could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a recent enough openssh server (>= version [7.2](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2)), then you get the option `restrict` in the [`authorized_keys`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/openssh-server/authorized_keys.5.en.html#restrict) file:

> **restrict**
>   **Enable all restrictions**, i.e. disable port, agent and X11 forwarding, as well as
>   disabling PTY allocation and execution of
>   `~/.ssh/rc`. If **any future restriction capabilities are added** to
>   `authorized_keys` files they will be included in this set.

then you can be assured that all possible restrictions apply, and will still apply in the future. Depending on needs, you might have to add additional enabling parameters after `restrict` (example: `pty` for interactive usage).

Comment: Thank you very much, accepted and +1. In fact, I already knew about the `restrict` option, because my SSH daemon is not too outdated and `man authorized_keys` described it prominently. However, I was hoping for a more consistent solution: If we leave away `restrict` (e.g. because we want *one* of the features), we have to name a lot of options which already might be given in the central `sshd_config` file. This sounds error prone. Plus, I don't want to give options to users which I have already forbidden. But since it seems that we have no better solution, I happily give the answer to you.

Comment: If you want *one* of the features, you keep `restrict` as first option, then, separated by a comma `,` you add back *that* feature. The same patch which added `restrict` added all enabling options matching the previous disabling options. Eg: `pty` was then added to cancel the implied `no-pty`, same with `agent-forwarding`, `port-forwarding`, `user-rc`, `X11-forwarding` etc.

Comment: Thank you very much again. That makes sense ...