# Redirect ssh output to file changes line endings

Tags: shell, ssh, newlines

First of all, if I do a simple `ssh admin@example.com "cat backup.tar" > backup.tar` this is not happening! So, there is something else converting it which I don't know.

I have the requirement to provide a backup of the current state of the system without giving access to the server. What I have done is the following:

1. Create a new user. Let's call him `username`
2. Allow only access via ssh-key
3. Put the keys into the `authorized-keys`
4. Change the command / shell in `/etc/passwd` to a custom script for `username`
5. Custom script gets the data by doing a database dump and copy some files and eventually creates a tar archive to the `stdout`
6. Make sure that there is no additional output to `stdout`.

To get the data you need to do: `ssh username@example.com > backup.tar`.

Now, nearly everything is working fine except that the line ending is changed. The `tar` gets bigger and I can see that every line has the dos line ending with a `^M` symbol. If I force `dos2unix` on the binary tar file the file matches the file on the server.

Why is this happening and what is changing the line ending?
I even simplified it to the following: The script on the server for `username` linked in `/etc/passwd` just make a `cat .viminfo` and the line endings are still transferred wrong when using the above `ssh` command to login as `username` and redirect the output to a file on my local machine.

Comment: @fra-san Thank you very much! That works. After knowing the solution from your comment and search what a pseudo-terminal is and why you should deactivate, I can find my use case at other exchange pages, too. Have tried to search for my problem and find a solution to that for more than an hour before.

Comment: I turned my comment into a full answer (and removed the comment).

Comment: Note: `ssh username@example.com whatever` will run the "shell" (the script used instead of a shell) with command line arguments `-c` and `whatever`. It totally depends on the script how (if) the script changes its behavior because of them. In general any program one wants to use as a shell should accept `-c code`. The program may ignore `-c` but it shall not be surprised nor misled by it. If your script recognizes `-c` then keep in mind `ssh` users logging in as `username` are able to use it. An edge case is when `-c` enables some functionality you don't want these users to have access to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is likely happening: when `ssh` is invoked with no command argument (and no `RemoteCommand` option specified), a [pseudo-terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) is by default allocated on the remote system for the session. That happens regardless of the command the remote system is configured to run. A pseudo-terminal is usually configured to translate line feed characters into carriage return + line feed sequences (`LF` → `CRLF`, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151963/315749) for a thorough explanation). Hence, the output of your script is written to a pseudo-terminal device, which alters it, and then sent to the client side.

The allocation of a pseudo-terminal can be prevented in several ways, including:

- invoking `ssh` with the `-T` option on the client side (or using `RequestTTY no` in `ssh`'s configuration file (likely `~/.ssh/config`));
- prepending `no-pty`  (note the white space) to the user's key in `authorized_keys` on the remote system;
- using `PermitTTY no` in the configuration of the SSH server on the remote system (possibly `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), likely using a `Match` conditional block to make it only affect a specific user); for instance:

  ```
  Match User="username"
    ForceCommand /path/to/your/script
    DisableForwarding yes
    PermitTTY no
  ```

  (which assumes a working command interpreter is set for the user in `/etc/passwd`; you may then want to lock the user's password and make sure they have no other means of logging in);
- (in your case, invoking `ssh` with a command argument should work too (e.g. `ssh user@host :`); though I would consider this no more than a workaround).

Of course, the most suitable option depends on your use case and, in particular, on whether the user is supposed to be allowed to choose.

See also:

- [Creating a UNIX account which only executes one command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3556/315749) — for a partially alternative approach, noting that, as pointed out [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645031/redirect-ssh-output-to-file-changes-line-endings#comment1208424_645031) to your question, a script used as a user's default interpreter does (may) prevent the user from getting a shell, but may also add exploitable elements of its own.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `ssh` to create a tunnel for my python script. The ssh command line doesn't do anything, it has no arguments, so it tries to open a shell and a pseudo-tty.

After ssh is launched using `subprocess.Popen`, the newline characters of my *python* script get broken into just linefeed, no carriage return, so the output of the python script goes to hell. On top of that, the python script will not run under `pytest` for reasons I don't understand that are related to the pseudo-tty.  I could get it to run under `pytest` with `-tt` supplied to the ssh, but still the normal python stdout gets corrupted. `-T` does not work with `pytest`.

I solved the problem by putting in a very long sleep command in the ssh command line; i.e. the equivalent of `ssh -L 1234:remote:1234 user@remote sleep 1000000`. Then no pseudo-tty funny business happens and the ssh tunnel will self close after 11 days. I only need the tunnel open for testing purposes, so the timeout is not a problem.